# How to use Grunt to report error for node js

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs

My question is how do I get grunt to report error like the default node start script. In my latest node/express project, I am trying to use Grunt task manager and changed the start script from

```
"start": "node ./bin/www"
```

to

```
"start": "grunt"
```

The problem is that when I run "npm start" or "grunt", the error report is not sufficient.

```
[nodemon]app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting   //error reported by grunt
```

When I change the start script back to "node ./bin/www", i was able to see error like

```
Error: Cannot find module mongoose   //error reported by node
```

This shows me that I have forgot to npm install mongoose. So how can i get Grunt to report that error?

**Edit:** another example of error reported by node

```
 MissingSchemaError: Schema hasnt been registed for model "Admin"   //error reported by node
```

**Edit 2:** The gruntfile.js config is as follow

```
/**** other configurations to minify and uglify ****/

nodemon: {
  dev: {
    script: 'server.js'
  }
},

// run watch and nodemon at the same time
concurrent: {
  options: {
    logConcurrentOutput: true
  },
  tasks: ['nodemon', 'watch']
}   
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve this:

- You can specify the `--stack` option on the command line:

  ```
  "start": "grunt --stack"
  ```
- You can enable the `stack` option in your `gruntfile.js`:

  ```
  grunt.option("stack", true);
  ```

Comment: --stack doesn't report the error for some reason. It just says "app crashed -- waiting for file changes before starting"

Comment: Then it's the grunt task that's running `nodemon` that's catching and reporting the error. You'd need to include the configuration for said task in your question.

Comment: I edited the question to show the gruntfile.js relating to nodemon.